# Project structure and importing packages

Tags: go

I'm just starting to learn Go and I'm wondering how to best organize my project and import packages. I created a project at `$GOPATH/src/my_project`. It contains the file `main.go` and the folder `foo` containing the file `bar.go`.

- $GOPATH/src/my_project

  - main.go
  - foo/

    - bar.go

My main.go looks as follows

```
package main

import (
    "./foo"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Main")
    foo.Baz()
}
```

Here is the foo.go

```
package foo

import "fmt"

func Baz() {
    fmt.Println("Baz")
}
```

It works the way I expect it to, but I wonder if this is really the right way to structure a project and import packages, because most tutorials only import packages from github and never from local.

Thanks for your answers..

Comment: nothing wrong here. you can read more questions and their answers using the search bar https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5Dproject+structure

Comment: Ignore random tutorials, read "How to Write Go Code" and abandon GOPATH builds and use modules.

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports are possible in Go but they are not encouraged to be used.

Instead you always use the full path of the package. In your case that would be `my_project/foo`. This is is relative to the `GOPATH/src` folder.

However, since we have `Go modules` now which make things a tiny bit more complicated to start with but have a lot of advantages in the long run.

Just earlier today I gave a step by step guide on how to set up a new project with Go modules: [After go install the import doesn't recognize the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65134537/after-go-install-the-import-doesnt-recognize-the-package)

The module name in this guide is the basis for your project then and all paths in the module build on that path. Let me give an example:

Let's say you name your module `github.com/yourName/myProject`. Then you can import the subpackage `foo` with `github.com/yourName/myProject/foo`.

Note: The module path should be the same as the git URL, that way you can just get the module with `go get`. If you don't plan on ever uploading the project to github or another git URL, you should still choose a unique name. Starting with a domain you own is a good idea -- for uniqueness.